# What is the name of the level with Luke Skywalker in Jedi Knight 2: Jedi Outcast

Tags: star-wars-jedi-knight-2

I see the cheat code that teleports you to a map for Jedi Knight 2: Jedi Outcast game, and because I know that Luke Skywalker is in the game, I need the name of the map with the mission with Luke Skywalker.

Comment: I am so impatient for the cool and interesting missions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once Kyle Katarn finds motivation to retrieve his lightsaber, he heads to the Jedi Academy on Yavin IV. The beginning of these levels, where you eventually meet up with Luke Skywalker, is called [Yavin Temple](http://www.ign.com/wikis/star-wars-jedi-knight-ii-jedi-outcast/Walkthrough:_Chapter_6_Yavin_Temple).

The name of that map is "[yavin_temple](http://www.gamefaqs.com/pc/516547-star-wars-jedi-knight-ii-jedi-outcast/cheats)". (Scroll down to "Skip Levels" on the linked website.)

This will not lead you directly to Luke Skywalker but it is the beginning of those missions that culminate in you retrieving your lightsaber.